# Overwriting the cart page layout in Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, mini-cart

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I want to change the layout of the page visible at the URL

> www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/

I could not find the `checkout_cart_index.xml` in my Magento 2.1.7 instalation.

*What* file shall I copy to my custom theme and *where* in order to overwrite the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the layout file from below location

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

and add in your theme.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Dont forget to run

```
static:content:deploy
Flush:cache
```